# Elasticsearch: storing a range of values in a field

Tags: elasticsearch, range

This is the first time I am asking a question.

I am planning to use Elasticsearch for storing certain data that I have.
The problem that I face is that I need to store a field's value as a range thats tolerated.
Like this-
the field name - tolerated pH
Example value - 5.1 - 7.0

I need to save it like this and when a query is executed, it has to see if the entered value lies in the range.

I can't find it in the reference and guide.
All I find is Range filter.
Can someone please help me out?
And guide me how it can be done?

Comment: Range Filter will give you the answer. You can filter other fields that you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create two fields

```
{ ...
  "minToleratedPh": 5.1,
  "maxToleratedPh": 7.0
}
```

And then use two `range` queries in order to check that the constraint `minPh < input_value < maxPh` holds true (just replace `input_value` by the pH value to check):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "minToleratedPh": {
              "lt": input_value
            }
          }
        },{
          "range": {
            "maxToleratedPh": {
              "gt": input_value
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need any more information regarding this issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot Val..!! This perfectly answers my question. I was just tweaking around the same idea. Thanks a ton for sorting it out...!!

Comment: Done :) Thanks again :)